# when the axios response.data is put on the dom all the click events disapear

Tags: javascript, axios

```
document.getElementById('listCategorie').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/file/categorieList', {})
    .then((response) => {
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    document.body.innerHTML = response.data
})
})
```

I know that if i use `$(document).on(event,..,..)` it works well but don't understand why. I don't like to use jquery at all, only vanilla js.

What I want is that when the axios response is put in the DOM, all the events continue working... but they disappear.

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = ''; ` is replace your entire  body. please add your listener on  inside`head` tag or else add the response in particular element instead of body

Comment: Hi  @prasanth  what do you mean by putting the listener in the head tag?

Comment: I edited your post to hopefully clarify things. Could you add some more details?

Comment: FWIW, the pure js equivalent of `$(document).on(event,..,..)` is `document.body.addEventListener(event, (e) => ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `document.body.innerHTML = something || '';`

Is replace your entire body. So add your 'js script' on inside the head tag

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script>...</script> //like this
  </head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

**or**

Else add the response in particular element instead of body

```
document.getElementById('listCategorie').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/file/categorieList', {})
    .then((response) => {
    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = response.data
})
})
```